# Using SystemJS in production without Traceur

Tags: javascript, systemjs

I want to use SystemJS to dynamically import AMD modules as well as `System.import()` modules on an as-needed basis. I can, of course, include `<script src="system.js"></script>`, but I'm getting an error that Traceur is not defined. I deliberately do *not* want to include Traceur, or any other dependencies, to keep requests to a minimum. Is there a version of SystemJS that allows importing AMD and `System.import` calls in one, semi-lightweight script?

Comment: Where are the answers? Chrome has most of es6 built in except for that pesky import statement.

Comment: I you setting System.transpiler?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#transpiler):

**Transpiler**

Type: `String` Default: `traceur`

Represents a module name for System.import that must resolve to either ***Traceur, Babel or TypeScript.***

You need to define one of the three above, its not possible to disable this feature.

Comment: It is possible to set the [transpiler to false](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1057), this still doesn't allow for importing of modules via `System.import()` calls.

Comment: Thanks. I have set to false, and traceur was no more requested. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `transpiler` option in `jspm` and (assuming it's just passed through) `systemjs` can be set to `false`, though currently<sup>[1]</sup> SystemJS has a hardcoded dependency on Traceur transpiler when module in ES6 format is detected.

The reason I mention this is, that I believe that your problem doesn't arise from AMD modules being used, but rather that some dependency in the modules that you use (or the modules that they use), are, in fact, written in ES6 format. Check your browser console for the revealing error message.

*<sup>[1]</sup> [Link to SystemJS sourcecode which handles ES6 module format](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/4d78a97d8e8c670c4ac7bae06125d7cbe63479fc/lib/esm.js#L35).*